# ASP.NET Model Binding can I give submit button a value and retrieve that value when its clicked?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, model-binding

Is it possible to use Model binding to get value of a button in the POST action method when its clicked on. I have a complex type and I wanted to have the user click on a button and retrieve the value of that button so I can use it to update the value of the complex type in the DB.

Note that at this point I have already saved the entity into the database and all that is left is to get a way to update properties of the complex type.
  If there is a recommended way to do that am willing to adopt that.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: You just need to give the submit button a name attribute and its value will be posted back. But your question is not clear. What do you mean by its already saved and you just want to update properties of the complex type? Why exactly do you need the value of the button? What value does the button have and how will you use it?

Answer (score 4):

You can use multiple submit buttons with different values to specify the way of update model.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MultipleCommand", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "submitForm" }))
{
    .
    .
    .
     <button type="submit" id="btnSave" name="Command" value="create">Save</button>
     <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="Command" value="update">Submit</button> 
}

public ActionResult(ComplexModel model, string Command)
{
    if(Command == "create")
    {
    }
    else if(Command == "update")
    {
    }
    else
    {
        // Default action
    }
}
```

For more info read [Handling multiple submit buttons on the same form - MVC Razor](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/cM1X161112-Handling-multiple-submit-buttons-on-the-same-form---MVC-Razor.html).

Comment: assuming the model inherits from IValidatableObject, will this solution participate in modelstate evaluation?  For example, can I see the parameter 'Command' in the model method 'Validate' - ?

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this

```
        public ActionResult Index(string submit) 
        ////Your action while clicking the button  and in the view button name should be submit
        {
            //// The string submit will have the value of the button
        }
```